# Schedule a task after inactivity (refreshable)

Tags: java

I'm looking for a way to schedule a task after some time, but i need to be able to delay the task if something happen.
For example

```
myMethod() {
    some code...

    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                LOGGER.info("close connexion");
            }
        },1000);

}
```

I need to reschedule the task in "run" if i come again in myMethod().
How to do?

Comment: move it in a separate method and call the method?

Comment: Use a `ScheduledExecutorService` instead of a `TimerTask`.  You can use the `ScheduledFuture` you get back from `schedule()` to cancel and re-schedule the task whenever you want to delay it.

Answer (score 0):

Solution #1

Please see at [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) that is available from java 1.5 It gives your method `scheduleWithFixedDelay` - so it re-schedules your task only after accomplishment. Another way to re-schedule task (with `schedule` method) right at the end of your method

Solution #2 - near the same signature of methods exists in the Spring [TaskScheduler](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html), but you can do it with help of annotated method of services.